# Approval of updated data in shiny application

Tags: r, authentication, shiny

Hi can someone point me to an example where a user of shiny app uploads data (provides inputs) and is updated only after the approval from admins or managers. As if sending a request to upload data which is only updated after approval. Thanks.

Comment: Let the user to upload all files. Make a database with a table of approved files with a column containing the file path of the already uploaded file. Restrict access of the database to managers. Create a CRON job updating the approved files and delete all files afterwards.

Comment: Let me try something like this.